# GCP: How to Retain resource on delete deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2

I want to retain External IP address created 1st time and use it again after deleting and recreating deployment.

I searched in documentation but did't find anything useful.
Is there any way I can specify in `.jinja` file to retain resources?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use always the same IP in Google Cloud Platform, you need to [reserve a static external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static).

After that you should define your service to [use that static IP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2a_using_a_service).

```
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: "YOUR.IP.ADDRESS.HERE"
```

Keep in mind that in Google Cloud Platform every time the VM instance is restarted it will get a different random external IP assigned. The same goes for GKE service, if you recreate it, it will get a different external IP each time it gets created. If you want to have the same IP, you will need to reserve a static external IP.